# OpenLayers - Draw polygon with exact number of points

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I have a UI where I give the user the ability to draw an area on the map, and I want him to draw a polygon with EXACTLY 4 points, how do I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

This is done in this example [here](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/draw-feature.html)

The code they use to draw the bow is:

```
var boxLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Box layer");

            map.addLayer(boxLayer);


            drawControls = {
                box: new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(boxLayer,
                    OpenLayers.Handler.RegularPolygon, {
                        handlerOptions: {
                            sides: 4,
                            irregular: true
                        }
                    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to draw a box, I want to draw 4 points at different locations one point at a time.

Comment: @Mehdiway you could use the beforeFeatureAdded event  (http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.6/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/Vector-js.html) then run some sort of if statementcounting the features

Answer (score 0):

Use a [polygon handler](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.13/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Handler/Polygon-js.html):

> Handler to draw a polygon on the map.  Polygon is displayed on mouse down, moves on mouse move, and is finished on mouse up.

To limit to 4 points use the sides property:

> sides {Integer} Number of sides for the regular polygon.